# Django: Overriding Postgres Database wrapper to set search path throws error

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I want to establish a connection with a postgres database in django. As it doesn't provide support for postgres schemas I am trying to set the search_path immediately after establishing a connection. To achieve this I have subclassed the DatabaseWrapper class and overridden the _cursor method as below:

```
from django.db.backends.postgresql.base import DatabaseWrapper


class DatabaseWrapper(DatabaseWrapper):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DatabaseWrapper, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def _cursor(self, name=None):
        cursor = super(DatabaseWrapper, self)._cursor(name)
        cursor.execute('SET search_path = schema_name')
        return cursor
```

Now the above code works fine for the application code that we have written but when I try access the detail screen of any object in the admin panel of django, I get the below error trace:

---

```
File "/Users/azharuddin.syed/Desktop/application/custom_db_engine/base.py", line 13, in \_cursor
cursor.execute('SET search_path = schema_name')
File "/Users/azharuddin.syed/Desktop/application/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
return super().execute(sql, params)
File "/Users/azharuddin.syed/Desktop/application/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
return self.\_execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self.\_execute)
File "/Users/azharuddin.syed/Desktop/application/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in \_execute_with_wrappers
return executor(sql, params, many, context)
File "/Users/azharuddin.syed/Desktop/application/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in \_execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/Users/azharuddin.syed/Desktop/application/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
File "/Users/azharuddin.syed/Desktop/application/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 82, in \_execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "SET"
LINE 1: ...6171701248_sync_1" NO SCROLL CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR SET search...
```

If I understand correctly then two queries are getting mixed together and getting executed at the same time. Why is this the case?

P.S: I am aware that we can pass options parameter with the search path while defining the connections in django but this is not working in my case as the DB is behind a proxy. Any other solutions will be welcomed.

Comment: Can't you just set the search path permanently for the user you are using? `alter user ... set search_path ..;`

Comment: No as we are using the same user to establish multiple connections with each connection setting its own schemas. Otherwise there will be table name conflicts.

Comment: doesn't django reuse the connection? and it would set the schema for the requests of other users.

maybe overriding the `execute` method in the `CursorWrapper` class would work? located at django/db/backends/utils.py